# How to Disconnect Port Already using in Java

Tags: java, serial-port, port

I want to Disconnect the Port which is used by this , code

```
public class TestSMS {

    private static String port = "COM10"; //Modem Port.
    private static int bitRate = 115200; //this is also optional. leave as it is.
    private static String modemName = "ZTE"; //this is optional.
    private static String modemPin = "0000"; //Pin code if any have assigned to the modem.
    private static String SMSC = "+000000"; //Message Center Number 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            try {
                GsmModem gsmModem = new GsmModem();
                gsmModem.configModem(port, bitRate, modemName, modemPin, SMSC);
                gsmModem.Sender("00000000", "Test Message"); // (tp, msg)

            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
```

I want to Disconnect this connection From COM PORT10 , Please Help Me!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Probably invoking the below method of GsmModem API may help. Please try and let us know the result.

REF: https://java.net/nonav/projects/playsim/sources/svn/content/trunk/hayesatsupport/src/net/java/dev/playsim/egsm/GsmModem.java

```
/**
 * ATH Disconnect Existing Connection
 *
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public void hangup() throws IOException {
    commandProcessor.hangup();
}
```